# how to prevent duplicate data from react

Tags: reactjs

my json object

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Banana",
   "category": "Food"
  }
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Milk",
   "category": "Food"
  }
  {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "Phone",
   "category": "Technology"
  }
]
```

when I map the category names found in my json data, the same category names are constantly repeating. how can I make sure this doesn't happen?

my code=

```
{card.map((element, i)=>{
<li>{element.category}</li>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing the `return` statement.

```
{
 card.map((element, i) => {
  return <li>{card.category}</li>
 }
}
```

And second, you are referencing the array `card` not the element.

```
{
 card.map((element, i) => {
  return <li>{element.category}</li>
 }
}
```

Even better:

```
{
 card.map(el => <li>{el.category}</li>)
}
```

Comment: you dont need return statement while displaying inside map

Comment: you do if you use {} instead of ()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` to filter out duplicates.

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Banana",
  "category": "Food"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Milk",
  "category": "Food"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Phone",
  "category": "Technology"
}];

const result = [...new Set(data.map(item => {
      return item.category;
    }))];
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import jsonFile from "./file.json"

const List = () => (
  <ul>
    {jsonFile.map(({ id, category }) => (
      <li key={id}>{category}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```